# How to Add New Line Feed while creating JSON file via VB.NET?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, formatting

I am using VB.NET to create Json file. 
Everything works fine. The Json Output code is good.
The problem is there is no linefeed between objects, array objects, etc.

My Code in VB.NET is below.

```
Dim mainlist As New ModJson

mainlist.Version = "123"

Dim billlist As New List(Of ModJson.Billlst)
Dim bill As New ModJson.Billlst
bill.b1 = "B1" & Environment.NewLine '----Tried this
bill.b2 = "B2" & vbCrLf '----- This one too.
bill.b3 = "B3"
billlist.Add(bill)
Dim litemlist As New List(Of ModJson.ItemLst)
For i As Integer = 0 To 1
Dim item As New ModJson.ItemLst
    item.i1 = 0
    item.i2 = 1
    litemlist.Add(item)
Next
bill.itemList = litemlist
mainlist.billLists = billlist
Dim output As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainlist)
```

My output is something Like this :

```
{"Version":"123","billLists":[{"b1":"B1\r\n","b2":"B2\r\n","b3":"B3","itemList":[{"i1":0,"i2":1}]}]}
```

The output is correct. Just there is no line feed.

I want something Like this :

```
{
  "Version": "123",
  "billLists": [
    {
      "itemList": [
        {
          "i1": 0,
          "i2": 1
        }
      ],
      "b1": "B1\r\n",
      "b2": "B2\r\n",
      "b3": "B3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I read many post but can't get one to explain me how to add a linefeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerializeObject` has a Overload method where we can provide the formatting required like below .

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainlist, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thanl you so much.